# How to get Slim Framework (v4) to output exceptions?

Tags: php, exception, slim

My app obviously throws `\Exception` when it needs to and I would love for Slim to send the response immediately once there is an `\Exception` thrown, and show the `\Exception` message in the json body.

However, it doesn't work (see below one-page example): the browser shows

```
Slim Application Error
A website error has occurred. Sorry for the temporary inconvenience.
```

And my php_error.log shows more details:

```
[30-Nov-2017 23:00:57 Europe/Madrid] Slim Application Error:
Type: Exception
Message: Error blah blah...
File: /Users/Lazhar/myproject/services/user-service/v1/src/app.php
Line: 24
Trace: #0 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#1 /Users/Lazhar/myproject/services/user-service/v1/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php(41): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#2 /Users/Lazhar/myproject/services/user-service/v1/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(327): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke(Object(Closure), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#3 /Users/Lazhar/myproject/services/user-service/v1/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#4 /Users/Lazhar/myproject/services/user-service/v1/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(301): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#5 /Users/Lazhar/myproject/services/user-service/v1/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(694): Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#6 /Users/Lazhar/myproject/services/user-service/v1/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#7 /Users/Lazhar/myproject/services/user-service/v1/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(588): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#8 /Users/Lazhar/myproject/services/user-service/v1/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(566): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#9 /Users/Lazhar/myproject/services/user-service/v1/src/app.php(30): Slim\App->run()
#10 /Users/Lazhar/myproject/services/user-service/v1/src/index.php(3): require('/Users/Lazhar/t...')
#11 {main}
View in rendered output by enabling the "displayErrorDetails" setting.
```

This is the app.php file...

```
<?php

// Autoload
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

// Instanciate our Slim App
$app = new \Slim\App();

// ERROR HANDLING

$c = $app->getContainer();
$c['errorHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($c) {
        return $c['response']->withStatus(500)
                             ->withJson([
                                'error' => true,
                                'message' => $exception->getMessage()
                            ]);
    };
};

$app->get('/exception', function($request, $response, $args) {

    throw new \Exception("Error blah blah...");

    return $response->withJson(['foo'=>'bar']);
});

// Run the show
$app->run();
```

Comment: Your code works on my machine. Try to add 'phpErrorHandler' as custom error handler: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/handlers/php-error.html#custom-php-error-handler

Comment: Aha, you are using Slim v4, sorry. Then try to use the `$app->setErrorHandler(callback)` and the `$app->setPhpErrorHandler(callback)` method.